# Differential equation must satisfy its edge conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have this variation problem

$$\text{Minimize} \; \int_0^1 \left( 12xt- \dot{x}^2-2 \dot{x} \right) \; dt$$

With the edge conditions $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)$ is "free".

And from here solve it:

$$x(t)\to -t^3 +c_1t+c_2$$

From here it should've been correctly. Now I must solve the equation and compute $c_1$ and $c_2$

However I'm not aware of the edge condition $x(1)$ as free. How do I solve this, and what does it exactly mean by "free"?

Result: $c_1$ should be $2$ and $c_2$ should be $0$.

*(Ps. If you can show it with Mathematica It would be great!)*

Comment: $c_1 = 2$ and $c_2 = 0$ lead to $x(0) = -2$???

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I have edited my post. Now it should be the correct algebra. Thank you.

Comment: Also is the functional you wanna minimize being integration from 0 to 2 or 0 to 1?

Comment: Doesn't "free" just mean that there _is_ no condition on $x(1)$? Though it looks strange that the integral goes to $t=2$ while the $t$ value that's explicitly specified as "free" is $x(1)$ rather than $x(2)$ (is this a typo?)

Comment: @ShuhaoCao It goes from 0 to 1. while i wrote the question i changed example and forgot to edit. It should be written correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the functional as $J(x)$:
$$
J(x) = \int_0^1 \left( 12xt- \dot{x}^2-2 \dot{x} \right)
$$
Then the minimizer $x$ satisfies the following (perturbing the minimum with $\epsilon y$):
$$ \frac{d}{d\epsilon} J(x + \epsilon y)\Big\vert_{\epsilon = 0} =0$$
Simplifying above gives us:
$$
\int^1_0 (12 y t - 2\dot{x}\dot{y} - 2\dot{y})dt = 0
$$
Integration by parts yields:
$$
\int^1_0 (12 y t + 2\ddot{x}y)dt - 2(\dot{x}+1)y\big|^1_0= 0
$$
Let's look at the boundary term: $(\dot{x}+1)y\big|^1_0 = (\dot{x}(1)+1)y(1) - (\dot{x}(0)+1)y(0)$. The term "free" from what I know would be a natural boundary condition. The essential boundary condition is $x(0)=0$ hence test function $y(0)=0$, the second term vanishes. On the natural boundary $t=1$, we do not impose anything on $y$'s value, hence we have to let $\dot{x}(1)+1 = 0$ to make variational problem well-posed, thus to get the differential equation $6 t + \ddot{x} = 0$.

And the final answer is: "$x(1)$ is free" leads us to the natural boundary condition
$$
\dot{x}(1)+1 = 0
$$
thus the coefficients are $c_1 = 2, c_2 = 0$.